# Parse >1,000 row subquery

Tags: database-design, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm building a tinder-like app, when users swipe left or right a `Swipe` object is created. I have a cloudcode query that gets a list of `_User`s neaby using `PFGeoPoint`, I then have a subquery which grabs all of the current users' `Swipe` objects and uses `doesNotMatchQuery` to make sure that the query never returns someone the user has already swiped on.

This all works but Parse limits it's queries to 1,000 rows which means if the user swipes on a thousand people then eventually they will start to see the same people again and again.

Is there any way around this?

Or will I have to ditch Parse and build my own solution?

Comment: Third party software often hits a brick wall when users go beyond the limited capabilities built into it.